# Animated R graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, gganimate

I try to generate animated plot about annual average precipitation of five different countries based on yearly rainfall data.

I use plotting package "gganimated" and "ggplot2" but I did not satisfy. I would like to create graphs like at 00:45 below video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adelgqOlZwE&t=18s

How I edit my code to create graph like this? Thanks in advance.

Note: Resource file can be downloaded at belowlink

https://easyupload.io/ud5u5m

```
 install.packages("gganimate")
library(gganimate)
install.packages("gifsski")
install.packages("av")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("rio")
library(dplyr)

data <- rio::import ("/Users/VATAN/Desktop/a/data.xlsx")

str(data)

# Plot and animate
p =  
  ggplot(data, aes(x= factor(Year), y=precipatation, group=Party, colour=Party)) +
  geom_line(size=2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#ff9933", "#006400")) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) +
  labs(title = 'Lok Sabha Election : % of seats won', 
        x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(Perc_Seats, accuracy = 1),
                vjust= -2), show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_dl(aes(label=Party), method="last.points") +
  transition_reveal(Year) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') + 
  ease_aes('cubic-in-out')

animate(p, fps = 10, width = 800, height = 400)
anim_save("election.gif")
```

Comment: What code do you exactly wish to edit? I don't see any plot here. It's really difficult to guess what you want to plot. The least would be to share your plot code.

Comment: Also, please ideally don't share links to data, but boil down your data to something that you can share in the question, or even better use one of R's many inbuilt data sets.

Comment: I edited my comment in order to clarfiy more. I gave youtube link  which shows type of plote I want.  I added my plot code but possibly is not work.